# Angular http post not passing data to django view

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I am trying to pass the data using angular $http post to django view but it is not happening. Every time I pass the data it shows empty dict, that means I am not using POST request correctly. I am new in integration django and angular app, so it would be great if someone can help me out with this.

**app.js**

```
vm.login = function() {
            vm.authMsg = '';
            var login_data = {'username': vm.account.username, 'password': vm.account.password};

            if(vm.loginForm.$valid) {

              $http
                .post('/login_app/', {login_data:JSON.stringify(login_data)})
                .then(function(response) {
                   console.log(login_data);

                  if ( !response.login_data ) {
                    vm.authMsg = 'Incorrect credentials.';
                    // vm.authMsg = response;
                  }else{
                    $state.go('app.dashboard');
                  }
                }, function() {
                  vm.authMsg = 'Server Request Error';
                });
            }
            else {
              vm.loginForm.account_username.$dirty = true;
              vm.loginForm.account_password.$dirty = true;
            }
          };
```

**views.py**

```
def login_app(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        print 'username', username
        print 'password', password
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print 'user', user
        if user:
            if user.is_authenticated():
                print 'user authenticate'
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({}), content_type='application/json')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Access Denied.<br>Wrong Credentials.</h1>')
```

**login.html**

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="login.login()" name="login.loginForm" novalidate="" class="form-validate mb-lg" method="post">

            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
               <input id="exampleInputUsername1" type="text" name="account_username" placeholder="Enter username" autocomplete="off" ng-model="login.account.username" required="" class="form-control" />
               <span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback text-muted"></span>
               <span ng-show="login.loginForm.account_username.$dirty &amp;&amp; login.loginForm.account_username.$error.required" class="text-danger">This field is required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
               <input id="exampleInputPassword1" type="password" name="account_password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="login.account.password" required="" class="form-control" />
               <span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback text-muted"></span>
               <span ng-show="login.loginForm.account_password.$dirty &amp;&amp; login.loginForm.account_password.$error.required" class="text-danger">This field is required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
               <div class="checkbox c-checkbox pull-left mt0">
                  <label>
                     <input type="checkbox" value="" name="account_remember" ng-model="login.account.remember" />
                     <span class="fa fa-check"></span>Remember Me</label>
               </div>
               <div class="pull-right"><a ui-sref="page.recover" class="text-muted">Forgot your password?</a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-lg">Login</button>
         </form>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from login import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                    url(r'^$',views.home, name='home'),
                    url(r'^login_app/$',views.login_app, name='login_app'),
                    )
```

Comment: It looks to me like angular is sending ``{'login_data':{'username':...}}`` but the django app is trying to read username/password from the top level dict. (not from within ``login_data``

Comment: @nephlm so I have to pass it in different variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

If you don't wrap/jsonify the login_data your existing view should be able to unpack it.  I'm pretty sure angular automatically handles the json conversion, but I don't think django does.

```
vm.login = function() {
        vm.authMsg = '';
        var login_data = {'username': vm.account.username, 'password': vm.account.password};

        if(vm.loginForm.$valid) {

          $http
            .post('/login_app/', login_data)
            .then(function(response) {
               console.log(login_data);
            [...]
```

Looks like you also want to look to `request.body` to get your json data.  If your in django < 1.4, it's something different.

```
def login_app(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.body
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print data
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')
        [...]
```

Comment: its not working. views.py printing this <QueryDict: {}>
username None
password None
user None

Comment: @User0706 in your views.py you have get post data with postData = json.loads(request.body); as angular send http request with application/json content type. so see what you get in postData with json.loads.

Comment: @nephlm not working with request.body. Throwing this error username = request.body.get('username')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: See the ``json.loads`` I added from ranakrunal9's comment.